# Increase the performance of Query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, query-performance

I am working on the existing view in SQL Server. My user reported now the performance is too slow. Can some one please let me know how can I increase the performance of the query/View

Query:

```
Select FH.ForecastID  
,FH.FiscalYear  
,FH.FiscalMonth  
,FH.ForecastStatusCode  
,FH.ForecastStatusDescription  
,WF.SubTypeID  
,WF.CustomerCode  
,WF.ProductID  
,WF.EndCustomerName  
,CU.RELShortName [Master Customer 1]  
,CASE WHEN (WF.EndCustomerName <> '' ) THEN CASE WHEN (CST.[Shortname] IS NULL ) THEN          CU.ShortName ELSE CST.[Shortname] END ELSE CU.ShortName END AS CustomerShortName
 ,CASE WHEN (WF.EndCustomerName <> '' ) THEN CASE WHEN (CST.[Shortname] IS NULL ) THEN CASE WHEN    (CU.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] = 'ASU') THEN 'AU' ELSE 'GP' END ELSE CASE WHEN (CST.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] =   'ASU') THEN 'AU' ELSE 'GP' END END ELSE CASE WHEN (CU.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] = 'ASU') THEN 'AU' ELSE   'GP' END END AS CustomerCategory
  , '' as  CustomerShortName    
,WF.EndCustomerName as [Disti End Customer]  
,CU.CustomerName [Sold To Customer Name]  
,WF.CustomerCode [Customer Sold To Number]  
,CU.CustomerClass  
,CASE WHEN (CU.CustomerClass <> 'Distributor' ) THEN CU.TerritoryCode ELSE WF.[Sales Office] END   AS [Sales Office]
,FH.REA_Onshore [Off Shore On Shore]  
,PR.ProductFamilyName [OSC Product Family(1)]  
,PR.ProductClassName [OSC Product Family(2)]  
,PR.ProductPartNumber  
,FH.ForecastTypeID  
,FH.ForecastTypeCode  
,FH.ForecastTypeDescription as ForecastTypeDescription 
,WF.SubType  
, ISNULL(WF.CreatedDate , '')  CreatedDate  
, ISNULL(WF.ModifiedDate, '')  ModifiedDate  
,WF.ModifiedBy  
,IsNull([MON-3], '0') [MON-3]  
,IsNull([MON-2], '0') [MON-2]  
,IsNull([MON-1], '0') [MON-1]  
,IsNull([MON00], '0') [MON00]  
,IsNull([MON01], '0') [MON01]  
,IsNull([MON02], '0') [MON02]  
,IsNull([MON03], '0') [MON03]  
,IsNull([MON04], '0') [MON04]  
,IsNull([MON05], '0') [MON05]  
,IsNull([MON06], '0') [MON06]  
,IsNull([MON07], '0') [MON07]  
,IsNull([MON08], '0') [MON08]  
,IsNull([MON09], '0') [MON09]  
,IsNull([MON10], '0') [MON10]  
,IsNull([MON11], '0') [MON11]  
,IsNull([MON12], '0') [MON12]  
,IsNull([MON13], '0') [MON13]  
,IsNull([MON14], '0') [MON14]  
 from TRX_ForecastDetailFlattened WF 
 left Join (
 SELECT ForecastID, FiscalYear, FiscalMonth, ForecastStatusCode, ForecastStatusDescription,   FH.ForecastStatusID, REA_Onshore, FH.ForecastTypeID, FT.ForecastTypeCode, FT.ForecastTypeDescription 
 FROM PRF_ForecastHeader FH 
 inner Join LKP_ForecastStatus FS with (nolock) on FS.ForecastStatusID = FH.ForecastStatusID  
 inner Join LKP_ForecastType FT with (nolock) on FT.ForecastTypeID = FH.ForecastTypeID  ) FH
 on WF.ForecastID = FH.ForecastID 

 left Join (
 select RELShortName, [ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME],CustomerName, CustomerClass,   TerritoryCode,CU.CustomerCode, ShortName ,[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY]
 FROM LKP_Customer CU 
 left join (SELECT distinct [ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME],[Shortname], [CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] FROM    [REA_DS].[dbo].[LCUS_CUSTOMER_SHORTNAME] ) CSTM on CSTM.[ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME] COLLATE    Latin1_General_CI_AI  = CU.[RELShortName] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 
 left Join PRF_Territory TE with (nolock) on TE.TerritoryID = CU.TerritoryID  
 left Join LKP_TerritoryGroup TG with (nolock) on TG.TerritoryGroupID = TE.TerritoryGroupID and TG.TerritoryGroupName = 'SALES REP COMPANY') CU
 on CU.CustomerCode = WF.CustomerCode  

 left Join (
 select ProductID, ProductPartNumber, ProductFamilyName, ProductClassName 
 FROM LKP_Product PR with (nolock) 
 left Join LKP_ProductClass PC with (nolock) on PR.ProductClassID = PC.ProductClassID  
 left Join LKP_ProductFamily  PF with (nolock) on PF.ProductFamilyID = PR.ProductFamilyID  ) PR
  on PR.ProductID = WF.ProductID  

 left join (SELECT distinct [ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME],[Shortname],[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] FROM    [REA_DS].[dbo].[LCUS_CUSTOMER_SHORTNAME] ) CST 
    on  WF.EndCustomerName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI  = CST.[ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME]   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 

 Where   CU.RELShortName <> '' and wf.CustomerCode <> '100000'
 group by  FH.ForecastID ,FH.FiscalYear ,FH.FiscalMonth ,FH.ForecastStatusCode    ,FH.ForecastStatusDescription ,WF.SubTypeID ,WF.CustomerCode ,WF.ProductID  
,WF.EndCustomerName ,CU.RELShortName ,WF.EndCustomerName ,CU.CustomerName ,WF.CustomerCode  ,CU.CustomerClass ,FH.REA_Onshore ,PR.ProductFamilyName  
,PR.ProductClassName ,PR.ProductPartNumber ,FH.ForecastTypeID ,FH.ForecastTypeCode   ,FH.ForecastTypeDescription ,WF.SubType ,WF.ModifiedBy  
,CST.[Shortname] ,CU.ShortName ,CST.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] ,CU.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] ,CU.TerritoryCode ,WF.[Sales Office] ,WF.CreatedDate ,WF.ModifiedDate
 , [MON-3], [MON-2], [MON-1], [MON00], [MON01], [MON02], [MON03], [MON04],[MON05], [MON06],  [MON07], [MON08], [MON09], [MON10], [MON11], [MON12], [MON13], [MON14]
```

Screenshot: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: how bout you show the SQL???

Comment: the optimizer is telling you to create an index...

Comment: Not sure why you get voted down so much, but as @TMcKeown says, the optimizer indeed tells you to create an index. See where things go after that. Going from the current query-plan it seems that most *work* is being spent in only a few parts; focus on those and your query performance probably will go up. Additionally, make sure that the statistics of the underlying tables are up to date. If you rather not do UPDATE STATISTICS <table> for each and every one, simply run sp_updatestats and have all tables in the database refreshed. Mind: this might take a while if you have a lot of (moving) data!

Answer (score 0):

```
--one of the way to increase performance is the usage of the  temp tables instead subqueries
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#FH') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #FH
SELECT  ForecastID ,
        FiscalYear ,
        FiscalMonth ,
        ForecastStatusCode ,
        ForecastStatusDescription ,
        FH.ForecastStatusID ,
        REA_Onshore ,
        FH.ForecastTypeID ,
        FT.ForecastTypeCode ,
        FT.ForecastTypeDescription
INTO    #FH
FROM    PRF_ForecastHeader FH
        INNER JOIN LKP_ForecastStatus FS WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON FS.ForecastStatusID = FH.ForecastStatusID
        INNER JOIN LKP_ForecastType FT WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON FT.ForecastTypeID = FH.ForecastTypeID
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            ForecastID
                     FROM   TRX_ForecastDetailFlattened
                   ) WF ON WF.ForecastID = FH.ForecastID  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#CU') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #CU
SELECT  RELShortName ,
        [ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME] ,
        CustomerName ,
        CustomerClass ,
        TerritoryCode ,
        CU.CustomerCode ,
        ShortName ,
        [CUSTOMER_CATEGORY]
INTO    #CU
FROM    LKP_Customer CU
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            CustomerCode
                     FROM   TRX_ForecastDetailFlattened
                   ) WF ON CU.CustomerCode = WF.CustomerCode
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            [ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME] ,
                            [Shortname] ,
                            [CUSTOMER_CATEGORY]
                    FROM    [REA_DS].[dbo].[LCUS_CUSTOMER_SHORTNAME]
                  ) CSTM ON CSTM.[ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = CU.[RELShortName] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
        LEFT JOIN PRF_Territory TE WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON TE.TerritoryID = CU.TerritoryID
        LEFT JOIN LKP_TerritoryGroup TG WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON TG.TerritoryGroupID = TE.TerritoryGroupID
                                                           AND TG.TerritoryGroupName = 'SALES REP COMPANY'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#PR') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #PR          
SELECT  ProductID ,
        ProductPartNumber ,
        ProductFamilyName ,
        ProductClassName
INTO    #PR
FROM    LKP_Product PR WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            ProductID
                     FROM   TRX_ForecastDetailFlattened
                   ) ON PR.ProductID = WF.ProductID
        LEFT JOIN LKP_ProductClass PC WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON PR.ProductClassID = PC.ProductClassID
        LEFT JOIN LKP_ProductFamily PF WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON PF.ProductFamilyID = PR.ProductFamilyID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                

SELECT  FH.ForecastID ,
        FH.FiscalYear ,
        FH.FiscalMonth ,
        FH.ForecastStatusCode ,
        FH.ForecastStatusDescription ,
        WF.SubTypeID ,
        WF.CustomerCode ,
        WF.ProductID ,
        WF.EndCustomerName ,
        CU.RELShortName [Master Customer 1] ,
        CASE WHEN ( WF.EndCustomerName <> '' )
             THEN CASE WHEN ( CST.[Shortname] IS NULL ) THEN CU.ShortName
                       ELSE CST.[Shortname]
                  END
             ELSE CU.ShortName
        END AS CustomerShortName ,
        CASE WHEN ( WF.EndCustomerName <> '' )
             THEN CASE WHEN ( CST.[Shortname] IS NULL )
                       THEN CASE WHEN ( CU.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] = 'ASU' )
                                 THEN 'AU'
                                 ELSE 'GP'
                            END
                       ELSE CASE WHEN ( CST.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] = 'ASU' )
                                 THEN 'AU'
                                 ELSE 'GP'
                            END
                  END
             ELSE CASE WHEN ( CU.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] = 'ASU' ) THEN 'AU'
                       ELSE 'GP'
                  END
        END AS CustomerCategory ,
        '' AS CustomerShortName ,
        WF.EndCustomerName AS [Disti End Customer] ,
        CU.CustomerName [Sold To Customer Name] ,
        WF.CustomerCode [Customer Sold To Number] ,
        CU.CustomerClass ,
        CASE WHEN ( CU.CustomerClass <> 'Distributor' ) THEN CU.TerritoryCode
             ELSE WF.[Sales Office]
        END AS [Sales Office] ,
        FH.REA_Onshore [Off Shore On Shore] ,
        PR.ProductFamilyName [OSC Product Family(1)] ,
        PR.ProductClassName [OSC Product Family(2)] ,
        PR.ProductPartNumber ,
        FH.ForecastTypeID ,
        FH.ForecastTypeCode ,
        FH.ForecastTypeDescription AS ForecastTypeDescription ,
        WF.SubType ,
        ISNULL(WF.CreatedDate, '') CreatedDate ,
        ISNULL(WF.ModifiedDate, '') ModifiedDate ,
        WF.ModifiedBy ,
        ISNULL([MON-3], '0') [MON-3] ,
        ISNULL([MON-2], '0') [MON-2] ,
        ISNULL([MON-1], '0') [MON-1] ,
        ISNULL([MON00], '0') [MON00] ,
        ISNULL([MON01], '0') [MON01] ,
        ISNULL([MON02], '0') [MON02] ,
        ISNULL([MON03], '0') [MON03] ,
        ISNULL([MON04], '0') [MON04] ,
        ISNULL([MON05], '0') [MON05] ,
        ISNULL([MON06], '0') [MON06] ,
        ISNULL([MON07], '0') [MON07] ,
        ISNULL([MON08], '0') [MON08] ,
        ISNULL([MON09], '0') [MON09] ,
        ISNULL([MON10], '0') [MON10] ,
        ISNULL([MON11], '0') [MON11] ,
        ISNULL([MON12], '0') [MON12] ,
        ISNULL([MON13], '0') [MON13] ,
        ISNULL([MON14], '0') [MON14]
FROM    TRX_ForecastDetailFlattened WF
        LEFT JOIN #FH AS FH ON WF.ForecastID = FH.ForecastID
        LEFT JOIN #CU AS CU ON CU.CustomerCode = WF.CustomerCode
        LEFT JOIN #PR AS PR ON PR.ProductID = WF.ProductID
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            [ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME] ,
                            [Shortname] ,
                            [CUSTOMER_CATEGORY]
                    FROM    [REA_DS].[dbo].[LCUS_CUSTOMER_SHORTNAME]
                  ) CST ON WF.EndCustomerName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = CST.[ACTUAL_END_CUSTOMER_NAME]   COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
WHERE   CU.RELShortName <> ''
        AND wf.CustomerCode <> '100000'
GROUP BY FH.ForecastID ,
        FH.FiscalYear ,
        FH.FiscalMonth ,
        FH.ForecastStatusCode ,
        FH.ForecastStatusDescription ,
        WF.SubTypeID ,
        WF.CustomerCode ,
        WF.ProductID ,
        WF.EndCustomerName ,
        CU.RELShortName ,
        WF.EndCustomerName ,
        CU.CustomerName ,
        WF.CustomerCode ,
        CU.CustomerClass ,
        FH.REA_Onshore ,
        PR.ProductFamilyName ,
        PR.ProductClassName ,
        PR.ProductPartNumber ,
        FH.ForecastTypeID ,
        FH.ForecastTypeCode ,
        FH.ForecastTypeDescription ,
        WF.SubType ,
        WF.ModifiedBy ,
        CST.[Shortname] ,
        CU.ShortName ,
        CST.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] ,
        CU.[CUSTOMER_CATEGORY] ,
        CU.TerritoryCode ,
        WF.[Sales Office] ,
        WF.CreatedDate ,
        WF.ModifiedDate
```